# Open Source SDN Controller

Tags: networking, controller, mininet, sdn

Which is the best open-source controller for Software Defined Networking(SDN) ? I have heard about Mininet, NOX, POX, Opendaylight, Floodlight etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So far, from my point of view Mininet is widely used. But still need experts suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't get direct answer for

> best open-source controller

as it depends on requirement and other factor.

I am not an expert when it comes to SDN but I have worked with SDN controllers like `Floodlight`, `opendaylight` along with `Mininet`.

We used Floodlight(FLC) as Controller and Mininet as provider for virtual Hosts, switches in FLC.

So technically mininet is not an SDN controller.

**Mininet:**

Mininet is a network emulator which creates a network of virtual hosts, switches, controllers, and links.

Mininet hosts run standard Linux network software, and its switches support OpenFlow for highly flexible custom routing and Software-Defined Networking.